# Most efficient way to see if any of textBoxes are empty C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a webform that can have multiple text boxes.

Lets say 3: txt1 txt2 txt3

obviously I can write the following code:

```
bool atleastOneTextboxEmpty=false;

If (txt1.Text.Tostring().Trim()=="")
{
atleastOneTextboxEmpty=true;
}
If (txt2.Text.Tostring().Trim()=="")
{
atleastOneTextboxEmpty=true;
}
If (txt3.Text.Tostring().Trim()=="")
{
atleastOneTextboxEmpty=true;
}
```

But i'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this( but so far I was not able to find it).

Note:
In my case I'm not allowed to use required field validators and form may have more textboxes which some of them are allowed to be empty(so I can't loop though all form textboxes).

Comment: Yes, that a 'little' improvement' .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a collection/array of textboxes and then you can do:

```
var textBoxCollection = new[] { txt1, txt2, txt3 };

bool atleastOneTextboxEmpty = textBoxCollection
                                   .Any(t => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text));
```

The above will check all the textboxes in the array `textBoxCollection` and check if any one of them have empty/whitespace only value.

Use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of triming and than comparing value with empty string. Remember `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is available with .Net framework 4.0 or higher.

---

Another option would be have these specific textboxes in a group control like `Panel` and then can use

```
yourPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(.....
```

Comment: Please look at my note: iI not completly familiar with your code but I think it check all textboxes in the form.  The question is how to see if TextboxA, TextboxB and TextboxC are empty  most in the most efficient way.

Comment: @SNash, missed your note.

Comment: @SNash, modified my code to verify only the required textboxes. The option would be to create an array/collection of those textboxes and iterate through it , like in the code above

Answer (score 4):

Lambda way! First part `Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()` gets all the textboxes on the form, the `Any` function check a condition.

```
Dim anyEmptyTBs = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Any(Function(tb) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write that simpler as:

```
bool atleastOneTextboxEmpty =
  txt1.Text.Trim() == "" ||
  txt2.Text.Trim() == "" ||
  txt3.Text.Trim() == "";
```

You can also put the controls in an array and check if any is empty:

```
bool atleastOneTextboxEmpty =
  new TextBox[] { txt1, txt2, txt3 }
  .Any(t => t.Text.Trim() == "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Repeater control and define a TextBox inside its . In the code behind, do what you did but just make one if statement that chacks the textbox with the ID in the control